# What is minimal MQSC command for IBM MQ to create user with permission to read from a queue?

Tags: authentication, authorization, ibm-mq

The target is a custom `IBM MQ v9.2` Docker image with basic development setup:

- a Queue Manager with a single Queue named 'MY_DEV_QUEUE'
- user A with permission to read from the queue
- user B with permission to write to the queue
- ability to connect to the MQ as admin (from MQExplorer)

(preferred user authentication is username+password)

I'm trying to create a MQSC script `custom.mqsc` that runs on startup of MQ.

*Dockerfile:*

```
FROM ibmcom/mq:9.2.2.0-r1

ENV LICENSE=accept
ENV MQ_DEV=false
ENV MQ_APP_PASSWORD=user-pwd
ENV MQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin-pwd
ENV MQ_QMGR_NAME=MY_DEV_MQ

COPY init/custom.mqsc /etc/mqm/
```

Setting `MQ_DEV=true` creates some queues with default names, but I would like to customize them as well as user permissions; and it is still not clear how to connect from MQExplorer in this case.

**What is the minimal set of commands in the MQSC script that fulfills these simple requirements?**

Comment: Which version of MQ? How do you plan to authenticate the user?  Will you configure ldap, user certs, or something else?

Comment: @JoshMc updated the question (v9.2, auth = username+password)

Comment: How will the container queue name authentication the user?